# Pegar numero do erro Axios

Tags: react, axios

Estou fazendo uma requisição, que me retorna o erro 401, porém eu não consigo pegar esse número

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
axios.post(config.urlBase + 'adicionar_empresa', formData)
.then(res => {
  if(res.data){
    this.refs.sucesso.openSucesso(2000);
    this.refs.load.closeLoad();
    this.limparCampos();
  }else{
    this.refs.erro.openErro(3000);
    this.refs.load.closeLoad();
  }
}).catch(e => {
  console.log(e)
});
```

Quando eu rodo o código a cima o console exibe isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu acreditava que no catch ele traria essa informação, mas não traz, alguém sabe como faço? Dei uma boa pesquisada e nada funcionou para mim.

obrigado!

Comment: Tenta dar um console.log em  error.response.status

Comment: Já tentei isso, não funciona... mas obrigado mesmo assim!

Comment: Puts que pena.
Se você não precisar obrigatóriamente usar o axios dá uma olhada no fetch e vê se ele te retorna os dados de erro corretos...

Comment: O parametro que recebe do `catch` é um objeto, e ao que me lembro (não testei) `e.response.status` deve dar-lhe o código de erro.

Comment: @Isac Não funciona, eu já testei

Comment: @OtavioSouzaRocha Dá que resultado ? E `console.log(e.response)` dá o que ?

Comment: @Isac Consegui resolver, vou postar o resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLUÇÃO:
tive que adicionar essa linha no meu .htaccess para habilitar o cors:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```